# Batch file to set IP

Tags: batch-file, ip

I am looking for a way to set a static IP and all the other functions such as subnet and DNS in a batch file maybe. So I just click it or put it in my start up folder and it will run everytime I boot my machine. I can click it if its easier, just at the moment I get set back to DHCP on every reboot.

Thanks

Comment: you need the [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) command.

Comment: do you want to input the info or do you want the batch to save those details?

Comment: And what is your specific question?

Comment: Do you know that on Windows you can configure in IPv4 properties of a network adapter to use by default automatic IP, subnet mask, gateway and DNS via DHCP (company) and define an alternate configuration using static IP and DNS (home)? The alternate configuration is used automatically if network cable is plugged-in and no DHCP server replies.

Comment: Sorry, I went it to set the IP and related details. Basically everytime I reboot it loses my static IP so instea dof typing it in I want a file I can run to set my IP, subnet and DNS. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not know how I can help you with the first part but for making it run every time you boot your pc what I do is I make a shortcut and then in the run window you type

```
shell:startup
```

to get to

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

and then I put the shortcut in that folder. After doing so whenever you start up your computer it should run file.

Hope this somewhat helps your problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh interface ip set address "connection name" static 192.168.0.101(what you want your ip to be) 255.255.255.0(subnet mask) 192.168.0.1.(default gateway)
```

you can check for your connection name at Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections